# MVC 3 SEO and Googlebot exceptions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, seo

I recently add the exception logger class to my web site and I noticed that Googlebots encounter exceptions.

I have a url like below, which I think SEO optimized:

http://www.psbaz.com/trophy/gamertrophies/%D8%AA%D8%B1%D9%88%D9%81%DB%8C-%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B2%DB%8C-batman-arkham-city/lst/5c63b8bb-e032-413d-9ebd-58348672408e/i_ps

As you may guess **trophy** is a Controller and **gamertrophies** is an action method.

So it is abvious that below urls encounter exceptions because of null paramters:

http://www.psbaz.com/trophy 
and
http://www.psbaz.com/trophy/gamertrophies

My question is that what steps should I take in favor of SEO:

Should I redirect these urls to 404 or doing something else?

Comment: Is this a question dealing with the ASP.NET MVC framework?

Comment: Yes Sir but if you have any experience in SEO, could you tell me that is it important the all parts of url be accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is more your content strategy then anything else.  What should a person get if they just type `trophy`?  I certainly wouldn't expect to go straight to a 404 page.  I would probably give some information about the different trophies.  I assume that since your action here is `gamertrophies` that there are other kind of trophies.  Well, tell me about the different categories of trophies.  If I were to type in `trophy/gamertrophies` then I'd expect to see a list of trophies about/for gamers, not shown the door.

"Better SEO" in this case is just providing content; certainly not redirecting to a 404 when a user types in a human-friendly URL.

Comment: Dear Charles, can you tell about following scenario: http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B006PP4136, if I remove B006PP4136 it returns 404?